# Changing the "Image" and "Title" on the web browser tab?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, internet-explorer

How do I change the default image that a browser (ex: the logo e on IE) shows on its tab for my sharepoint site with a custom image. 
I understand it should be 16*16.

But where exactly should I be putting the image?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to drop a small favicon.ico file at the root of your web application within IIS (next to the web.config) or edit the master page to link to your custom file if it's host somewhere else.

A good tutorial on this can be found here : http://blog.tedpattison.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=8

Comment: Thanks It does not let me do it though as it is an asp.net server page. Is there a workaround. I was however able to put it on my master page. Unfortunately the server page I am trying to put it on is independent of the master.